# IIS 7.0 POST request fails while GET succeeds for same page

Tags: .net, iis

I have deployed a .NET wcf webservice on IIS 7.0 on a windows 2008 server (32-bit).
When I am opening the svc and wsdl in browser ( which works as GET request) it works fine.
However on making a webservice call (SOAP request using POST) on same svc, it returns a 404 error. 
Found a similar post [IIS 404/405 errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830888/iis-404-405-errors) and following the response, reinstalled IIS and ASP.NET but error remains.
This webservice has been deployed and working on many servers. This scenario is happening only one of the machines.

Comment: Have you looked at [How do I send SOAP Request to WCF Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641126/how-do-i-send-soap-request-to-wcf-service)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using polling duplex binding for your wcf service there will be delay.. check whether you have included MaxOutputDelay

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple that would cause this behavior.   I'd think setting IIS failed request tracing - http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis/ -  on response code 404 and looking through the trace data would reveal what's happening under the covers.

That in turn might help narrow down the solution.